# Select radio button value in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a form with three radio buttons.

```
<form name="contact">
    <label>Type</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="car" value="car" checked>Car
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="boat" value="boat">Boat
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="home" value="home">Home
    </label>
</form>
```

I'm writing integrated tests in Protractor.

I'm having problems selecting a radio button value. I've tried `clicking` by ID:

```
//click boat 
element(by.id('boat')).click();
```

When I run my test, I get the following error:

```
Message:
  Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="boat"])
Stack:
  NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="boat"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work...

setup:

- protractor 4.0.10
- selenium standalone server 2.53.1
- chromedriver 2.25

config.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

spec.js:

```
describe('form', () => {
  it('should click boat', () => {
    // test page using the html above. generated a non-angular page
    // on port 8000
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('http://localhost:8000/index.html');

    element(by.id('boat')).click();

    // pause to take a screenshot
    browser.pause();
  });
});
```

html screenshot running up to the `browser.pause` (opened up dev tools to show the html):

[image: html result]